# Why is no database shown in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My SQL Server Object Explorer is not showing any databases:

[image: SQL Server Object Explorer]
[image]

I also get an error `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. ...`. When I run the website, the error being shown is `The system cannot find the file specified`. Furthermore, `SQL Server` is missing from `Services`:

[image]

(It was installed together with Visual Studio and was never used separately)

Yesterday, everything worked like charm; I had multiple databases with tables and was able to access the data. Today, the same project can't even start, no db's either. What's wrong with Visual Studio here? Thanks

Comment: Check if your SQL server is running. Type in cmd `services.msc` and see if `SQL Server` is set to automatic.

Comment: @Milan I don't have it in the list, neither do I have it in `All Programs`. Is there a command to start/restart `SQL Server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Visual Studio does not come with `MS SQL Server` in the default installation. It is necessary to install `SQL Server Data Tools` from the MS website manually. VS custom installation also allows to do that, but you will need an installer. Just make sure to select `SSDT` in the custom installation components menu. Additionally, I also ran an update from VS itself that allowed me to install `SQL Server` 2008, 14, and 16. I am finally able to access DB in VS!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem before. Took me a while to figure it out. What you need to do is go here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299

In my case, i'm using SQL Server **2014** Management Studio. You must find the one that suits the version of SQL studio that you're using (2008, 2012, 2014).

Click the big download button and now, it is very important that you choose the proper version. Check:

- `Express 32BIT\SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe` if you're running on a 32-bit PC, or
- `Express 64BIT\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` if you're running on a 64-bit PC

It is very important that you install Express version.

Next, once you install that, you should be able to see the `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` in your `services.msc`, along with few other SQL services installed.

Open Visual Studio 2015 and in **SQL Server Object Explorer** window right click on `SQL Server` and choose `Add SQL Server...` option. It should prompt you to connet to the server from SQL Server Management Studio.

If you kept everything by default during the installation, just type `.` (dot) for the **Server name** and click **connect**. Now it should load the database.